# Same tpl.php for multiple blocks

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I have 14 blocks added through Drupal interface, for all of them I was override tpl.php file because I need some changes there (like `block--block--1.tpl.php`).

What I want to do is to create just one tpl.php file and apply it for all these blocks. So, if I need to change something someday, I change it just in one file instead 14 files.

How I can accomplish that in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [template suggestion](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions) for Drupal 7, we have a general format as:

> block--[region|[module|--delta]].tpl.php
>
> base template: block.tpl.php
>
> Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors, listed from
>   the most specific template to the least. Drupal will use the most
>   specific template it finds:
>
> block--module--delta.tpl.php block--module.tpl.php
>   block--region.tpl.php "module" being the name of the module and
>   "delta", the internal id assigned to the block by the module.

Now, in order to override and define your own suggestions apart from these, you can provide new template suggestions in your theme template.php file file using [template_preprocess_block](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7.x) as:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'common_block_template';
}
```

Now you place(create) this common-block-template.tpl.php file in your themes templates folder and it will be default template for all your blocks and don't forget to clear drupal cache.

**Note**: This templates will be applied to every block present in your Drupal 7 website i.e. user login block, content block etc.. So make sure you do define logic as per your page requirements as for example if you want to limit this template suggestion for just a uri name `mypage`, then

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
 if (current_path() == 'mypage') {
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'common_block_template';
 }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
To target delta (with numeric values & to avoid custom module block) the were created using Drupal 7 site building block module:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    $block = $variables['elements']['#block'];
   if (is_numeric($block->delta)) {
      $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'common_block_template';
    }
 }
```

If you need to target just block which has delta of 1 then:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
    $block = $variables['elements']['#block'];
   if ($block->delta == 1) {
      $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'common_block_template';
    }
 }
```

Comment: I'm getting these errors: `Warning: array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in theme()` and `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in theme()`. Also, can I check `if ($variables['id'] == 1)` and apply template for block with ID 1 (in this case) only?

Comment: sorry, I missed it is double dimensional array, It should be $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][]. Check update.

Comment: Thank you. Errors is gone. Now, I just need to apply this suggestion for block with ID 3,7,8,11...how to do that? I tried to check ID (as I wrote in my previous comment) but template isn't applied.

Comment: I suppose you mean block--block-1.tpl.php, the numeric 1 here i.e. the delta part. You can check if delta part is numeric or not and apply your suggestion. Check the update

Comment: So, I can also check `if (is_numeric($variables['block']->delta) && $variables['block']->delta == 1)` to target block with delta 1?

Comment: If you just want to target 1 then no need for extra checking of  if its number with && it just take extra process time just check for if delta == 1 and no need to check if its numeric.

Comment: If I add this suggestion in `preprocess_block` it's add theme suggestion in array, but if I want to add just for one block with specific delta it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

Try `block--block.tpl.php` instead.